# The picture goes up because the description is long how can I fix this?

Tags: swift, image, uiviewcontroller, label, uiimageview

[image]

[image]

[image: Main]

When the picture description is long, my picture disappears, I can't see it. How can I show full size of text and full size of images?

How can I scroll the text up and down?

FavoriteDetailViewController

```
import UIKit
import ProgressHUD

class FavoriteDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
   @IBOutlet weak var shortdescriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var favoriteImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var favoriteTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    
    var breed: Breed!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        populateView()
    }
    
    private func populateView() {
        favoriteImageView.kf.setImage(with: breed.image?.asUrl)
        favoriteTitleLabel.text = breed.name
        descriptionLabel.text = breed.description
        shortdescriptionLabel.text = breed.shortDescription
    }
    
    @IBAction func favoriteButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let name = nameField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces),
              !name.isEmpty else {
            ProgressHUD.showError("Please enter your name")
            return
        }
        print("Hello \(name)")
    } 

}
```

I made the text smaller but it's very illegible

I dropped the spacing, it looks bad too

I want to make the whole text look nice and not spoil the picture. What is the solution? Is it possible to move the label up and down?

Comment: Use a `UITextView` instead of a label, that way, you can scroll the text only if it's too long. Make it non-editable.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with (content hugging) or (content compression) settings in stackview? or do i need to replace UILabel with UITextView?

Comment: Give it a try with SwiftUI, set the frame with min- and max-height for desired appearance.

Comment: Do you need the stackView with the image as first item? Could looking good to use the image as background and put the text on top with background opacity of 0.9

Comment: I think use UIstackview nest in UIScrollView can reslove your problem